# DNN, iFinity, and 404s?

Tags: .net, iis-7, dotnetnuke

Error logs in a DotNetNuke (DNN) site are filling up with errors like that of below. Are these important? They appear to be 404 related, but why would they be causing a general exception as 404s are being handled by iFinity Url Master. Is there a way in DNN to stop reporting on them?

**General Exception**
AssemblyVersion: 6.2.0
UserID: -1
UserName:
ActiveTabID: 678
ActiveTabName: 404
RawURL: /Portals/Portals/0/favicon.ico
AbsoluteURL: /404.aspx
AbsoluteURLReferrer:
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
DefaultDataProvider: DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider
ExceptionGUID: b546f73a-6e44-48d2-9c6e-6bddc70c9ff4
InnerException: Unhandled Error:
FileName:
FileLineNumber: 0
FileColumnNumber: 0
Method:
StackTrace:
Message: System.Exception: Unhandled Error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors can't be avoided without modification to the DotNetNuke core.

Basically what happens is that the Url Master module handles the 404 error and clears it, but the DNN exception handling still picks the error up and logs it.

This has been logged in the DotNetNuke gemini bug tracking system but not fixed as yet.  It's mentioned in the release notes section of the Url Master install.

As long as your 404 error process is working OK, then there is nothing to worry about.

[Exception Module still logs error if error has been cleared](http://support.dotnetnuke.com/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?id=14021&PROJID=2)

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Good to know its working as its supposed to and not an error in setup.

Comment: Second question, why is the favicon returning the 404? The URL for it is listed in an incorrect location, but I cannot find reference anywhere to said location. There is an extra "portals" in the URL. /Portals/Portals/0/favicon.ico

Comment: I'm not sure about that one - the Url Rewriting scheme shouldn't affect the way the portal icon works.   Is it like this for every portal on your site?

Comment: Only portal in this installation. Another site has a similar configuration, but not returning the 404 / favicon General Exception.

Comment: Found the culprit. An outside site was linking to the favicon. No referrer URL was being logged so it shows as the 404 tab.

Comment: 404 errors still appearing in the logs. Cannot find the ticket in DNN anymore. Any idea of progress on this? Logs are still filled with hundreds of 404s on images. Simply want to ignore and not log 404s into the Event Viewer logs even if it means making an easy core change every few updates.